# Looking to list all files/dirs ignored by rsyncs exclude file

Tags: linux, centos, backup, scripting, rsync

I have around 7 or 8 servers, which I rsync down to my local LAN each night.

All of these rsync jobs use a common excludes.txt, to filter out files or directories I dont want mirroring.

Now, the excludes.txt contains some dirs which are common to all servers, but also a lot of directories (and patterns) which are specific to an individual server. Of course, they are all intermingled together and uncommented.

Im trying to get a handle on all of this, and move all the server specific patterns into separate files, specific for each individual server.

Im not yet sure how best to go about this, as from what I can see from the man page, rsync doesn't provide any options to display which files/dirs it has ignored.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run rsync with extra verbosity:

```
rsync -vv
```

This will show why each file is being included/excluded.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Rsync --list-only
```

list the files instead of copying them this will let you see which files are going to be copied.